# Multithread increases calculation time - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, montecarlo

I was asked to **check calculation time depending on number of threads** working on the problem. Therefore I had written a program that calculates integral using Monte Carlo method. I am dividing the range for number of threads. After that I stats threads, which calculate their part, and finally sum partial results to get general one.

The problem is that **time of calculation increases with number of threads instead of decreasing** (i7 processor, Windows 7)

A few people working on it, and we do not know why is that. I hope someone will give me an advice.
I attach code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;


public class Runner {

private static final int MAXT = 10; // maksymalna ilość wątków
static PrintWriter outM;
static PrintWriter outMTime;

public static void main(String[] args){

    double xp = 2;
    double xk = 3;




    filesOp();

    // Wypisywanie kolumn tabeli
    for(int threadNumber=1; threadNumber<=MAXT; threadNumber++){
            outM.print("\t"+ threadNumber);
            outMTime.print("\t"+ threadNumber);
        }

    double time1;
    double time2;

    //double startTime=System.currentTimeMillis(); // Przed wystartowaniem programu

    for(int n=10000; n<=10000000; n=n*10){

        System.out.println("Licze dla: " + n + " punktow.");


            outM.print("\n"+n);
            outMTime.print("\n"+n);


        for(int threadNumber=1; threadNumber<=MAXT; threadNumber++){

            outM.print("\t");
            outMTime.print("\t");

            time1=System.nanoTime();
                multiThread(xp, xk, n, threadNumber);
            time2=System.nanoTime();

            outMTime.print((time2-time1)/1000000);
            // czas pracy dla danej liczby wątków

        }

    }

    outM.close();
    outMTime.close();

}


public static void multiThread(double xp, double xk, int n, int threadNumber){
    // Funkcja licząca całkę wielowątkowo.
    // Całka do policzenia jest dzielona pomiędzy wątki

    ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> results = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double>();

    for(int i=0; i<threadNumber; i++){ 

        MonteCarlo mc = new MonteCarlo( xp+(i*((xk-xp)/threadNumber)), xp+((i+1)*((xk-xp)/threadNumber)), (int)(n/threadNumber), results);


        Thread t = new Thread(mc);
        threadList.add(t);
        t.start();

    }

    //for(int j=0; j<threadNumber; j++){ // pętla czeka na zakończenie wątków
    for(Thread t : threadList){
        try {
            //while(t.isAlive()){}
            //threadList.get(j).join();
            t.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    double wynik = 0;
    //for(int k=0; k<results.size(); k++){
    for(double r: results){ 
        //wynik = wynik + results.remove();
        wynik= wynik + r;
    }


    outM.print(wynik);
}



public static void filesOp(){
    File fileTemp;

    fileTemp = new File("wyniki.txt");
    if (fileTemp.exists()) fileTemp.delete();


    fileTemp = new File("pomiary.txt");
    if (fileTemp.exists()) fileTemp.delete();


    try {

        outM = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("wyniki.txt", true));
        outMTime = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("pomiary.txt", true));    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}


public class MonteCarlo implements Runnable{

    double xp; 
    double xk; 
    long n;
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> results;

    MonteCarlo(double xp, double xk, long n, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> results){
        this.xp=xp;
        this.xk=xk;
        this.n=n;
        this.results=results;
    }

    //funkcja dla ktorej obliczamy calke
    private static double func(double x) {
        return x*x+3;
    }


    private static double funcIn(double x, double y) {
        if (( y > 0) && (y <= func(x)))
            return 1;
        else if (( y > 0) && (y <= func(x)))
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    //random number from a to b
    private static double randomPoint(double a, double b) {
        return  a + Math.random() * (b-a);
    }  

    public void run(){      
        double yp, yk, calka;
        int pointsIn;


        yp = 0;
        yk = Math.ceil(Math.max(func(xp), func(xk)));

        pointsIn = 0;

        for (long i=0; i<n; i++) {
        pointsIn += funcIn(randomPoint(xp, xk), randomPoint(yp, yk));
        }

        calka = (pointsIn / (double)n) * ((xk-xp) * (yk-yp));       

        results.add(calka);

        }


}
```

And the example of results:

> 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
>
> 10000  6.185818    2.821405    3.721287    3.470309    4.068365    3.604195    4.323075    4.192455    6.159694    4.239105
>
> 100000    10.994522   15.874134   34.992323   40.851124   36.199631   49.54579    45.122417   61.427132   55.845435   60.7661
>
> 1000000   108.653008  274.443662  340.274574  407.054352  437.455361  469.853467  496.849012  584.519687  571.09329   594.152023
>
> 10000000  1066.059033 2877.947652 3600.551966 4175.707089 4488.434247 5081.572093 5501.217804 6374.335759 6128.274553 6339.043475

Comment: You should not include the time it takes to create and start a thread in your calculations, they take a significant time to create and start. Also, creating thousands of objects could also skew your statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem most likely lies in

```
private static double randomPoint(double a, double b) {
    return  a + Math.random() * (b-a);
}
```

`Math.random()` performs poorly under heavy contention. If you are using java 7 or later, try this instead:

```
private static double randomPoint(double a, double b) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Switching to `ThreadLocalRandom` made the execution time of `randomPoint` go up from 151 seconds to 203 seconds (on my computer, java 8)

Comment: @Aerus Well, on my machine it resolved the problem (Java 8 too).

Comment: Agree. The same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663178/inefficient-threads-in-java)

Comment: Great! Now it works great! I was not expecting that the problem could be there! But i don't really get why is that :)

Comment: @Niko If you are curious, you can just explore, how `Math.random()` is implemented. You will see a while loop `do {...} while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed))`. The problem is in this `compareAndSet` - under heavy load, it often returns `false`, so a loop body has to be executed many times before it returns new random value.

Answer (score 0):

Using static funtions frequently is one of the pitfalls in Multithreading.
A more general answer can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343157/static-method-behavior-in-multi-threaded-environment-in-java) post already.